# How to create a virtualenv with Python3.3 in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python3

I'm running Precise Pangolin amd64. I installed Python 3.3 from ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes.

Now I want to actually *use* this new Python version in a virtualenv. But How can I do this? I get the following error:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.3
The --no-site-packages flag is deprecated; it is now the default behavior.
New python executable in /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/python3.3
Also creating executable in /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    __boot()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.py", line 2, in __boot
    import sys, imp, os, os.path   
ImportError: No module named 'imp'
ERROR: The executable /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/python3.3 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs' (should be '/home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

If instead, I explicitly use `python3.3` to call virtualenv, I get this error:

```
$ python3.3 /usr/bin/virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 2, in <module>
    import virtualenv
ImportError: No module named 'virtualenv'
```

I'm stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** Following the advise by @thefourtheye, I purged my local `site-packages` directory (effectively only deleting `site.py`). Now I'm getting a step further, but *virtualenv* complains about a missing `easy_install`:

```
 Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory:   
'/home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/easy_install' while executing command    
/home2/USERNAME/.virt...rk3/bin/easy_install /usr/share/python-virtualenv/pip-1.1.tar.gz
```

I did install the package `python3-setuptools`, which installs the Py3 version of easy_install.

**EDIT2:**

Here's the verbose output, without explicitly passing `--distribute` and `--no-site-packages`, as these two switches are default behaviour of my *virtualenv*:

```
$ virtualenv --verbose -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.3
Creating /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3
Symlinking Python bootstrap modules
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/config-3.3m
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/os.py
  Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: posix
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/posixpath.py
  Cannot import bootstrap module: nt
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/ntpath.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/genericpath.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/fnmatch.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/locale.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/encodings
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/codecs.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/stat.py
  Cannot import bootstrap module: UserDict
  Cannot import bootstrap module: copy_reg
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/types.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/re.py
  Cannot import bootstrap module: sre
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/sre_constants.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/sre_compile.py
  Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: zlib
  Cannot import bootstrap module: _abcoll
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/warnings.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/linecache.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/abc.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/io.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/_weakrefset.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/copyreg.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/tempfile.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/random.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/__future__.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/collections
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/keyword.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/tarfile.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/shutil.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/struct.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/copy.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/base64.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/bisect.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/_dummy_thread.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/hashlib.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/heapq.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/hmac.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/reprlib.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/rlcompleter.py
  Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/weakref.py
Creating /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/site-packages
Writing /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/site.py
Writing /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/orig-prefix.txt
Writing /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/no-global-site-packages.txt
Creating parent directories for /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/include
Symlinking /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/include/python3.3m
Creating /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin
New python executable in /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/python3.3
Changed mode of /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/python3.3 to 0o755
Also creating executable in /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/python
Changed mode of /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/python to 0o755
Testing executable with /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/python3.3 -c "
import sys
prefix = sys.prefix
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    prefix = prefix.encode('utf8')
if hasattr(sys.stdout, 'detach'):
    sys.stdout = sys.stdout.detach()
elif hasattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer'):
    sys.stdout = sys.stdout.buffer
sys.stdout.write(prefix)
"
Got sys.prefix result: '/home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3'
Creating /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/distutils
Writing /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/distutils/__init__.py
Writing /home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/distutils/distutils.cfg
Using existing distribute egg: /usr/share/python-virtualenv/distribute-0.6.24.tar.gz
Installing distribute..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing existing pip-1.1.tar.gz distribution: /usr/share/python-virtualenv/pip-1.1.tar.gz
Installing pip...
  Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/easy_install' while executing command /home2/USERNAME/.virt...rk3/bin/easy_install /usr/share/python-virtualenv/pip-1.1.tar.gz
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2283, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 938, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1054, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 643, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 976, in call_subprocess
    cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 818, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home2/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/easy_install'
```

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, can you try this command (excluding `distribute`): `virtualenv --no-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3`?

Comment: I tried with `--setuptools` as well, and the result is exactly the same (including the installation of distribute).

Comment: In 14.04 everything works painlessly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Take backup of site-packages.

   `cp -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ /tmp/site-packages`
2. Truncate that directory

   `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`
3. Now try the same

   `virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3`
4. To install without pip

   `virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3 --no-pip`

**EDIT:** Looks like the version of virtualenv (1.7.1.2) and python3.3 are not compatible. So, please try this

1. Uninstall python-virtualenv using `sudo apt-get remove python-virtualenv`
2. `wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py; sudo python ez_setup.py` This will install latest easy_install.
3. `sudo easy_install pip`
4. `sudo pip install virtualenv`
5. `virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3`

Comment: interesting, now I'm getting a step further, but still not all the way there. See my updated question

Comment: I am going through the virtualenv code. It would be helpful, if you could execute the same command with increased verbosity and show us the complete output.


`virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3 --verbose`

Comment: got it, see my updated question.

Comment: Have been analyzing for more than two hours. Looks like distribute doesnt install the easy_install scripts in bin directory. We can install them manually later. So just to install virtualenv, try to install without pip, as I have updated in the answer

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Unfortunately, I get `virtualenv: error: no such option: --no-pip`. My virtualenv version is 1.7.1.2, and I instlled it via `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I managed to get the same error message which you are getting. 

Now, first uninstall python-virtualenv using


`sudo apt-get remove python-virtualenv`

and then do 


`wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py; sudo python ez_setup.py` This will install latest easy_install.

Then, `sudo easy_install pip`


And then `sudo pip install virtualenv`


And then `virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3`

Comment: Instead of installing virtualenv manually, I just downloaded the .dev packge for Ubuntu Raring from http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/all/python-virtualenv/download and installed it via `dpkg -i`. Seems to work now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Might be of interest to some that virtualenv has deprecated --no-site-packages and no access to global site-packages is now the default.

Comment: Can I use it to create a python 2 venv?  (just kidding!) (no seriously!)

Comment: Two years after linux distros have updated their package repositories, so no need to install packages. Also both `--no-site-packages` and `--distribute` options have been deprecated and have no effect. Just running `virtualenv <name> -p /usr/bin/python3` will do the job

Answer (score 59):

Python 3.3 has venv built-in.

http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv

Simply run

```
pyvenv-3.3 /path/to/environment
```

And then to activate it

```
source /path/to/environment/bin/activate
```

This built-in version of virtualenv is much more flexible than what you're probably used to.  For example, you can extend EnvBuilder to do pretty much whatever you want.  You can copy an example implementation of EnvBuilder from the link below and play around with it:
http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#an-example-of-extending-envbuilder

That script above likely does most of what we expect to get out of virtualenv.  So if you just need a virtualenv with easy_install and pip, you should be good to go.

See [@MarkOfSine](https://askubuntu.com/users/203582/markofsine)'s edits below for clarification on how to get running if you're still confused.

---

To add to the above, and as per docs:
For example, after executing: `pyvenv-3.3 /path/to/my_project/venv`
You can run `distribute_setup.py`, which seems to do various things, but essentially you end up with `easy_install` in your `./my_project/venv/bin` directory.
This can then be used to install `pip` and the like.

It does not say where you should get `distribute_setup.py` from, so I downloaded from:

```
http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
```

and using the activated environment:

```
cd /path/to/my_project
source venv/bin/activate
```

ran :

```
python distribute_setup.py
```

and

```
easy_install pip
```

Which then completed the setup of the virtual environment more inline with virtualenv on python 2.x

Comment: nice one - i wasn't aware of this ...

Comment: actually, this seems not to be a "real" virtualenv. There's neither pip nor easy_install available after activating it.

Comment: @andreas-h
You need to install those yourself.  That doesn't make it not "real".

Comment: @andreas-h Also, it's designed so that you can create a script to add whatever you want yourself.. see http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#an-example-of-extending-envbuilder

Comment: When you terminal keeps yelling about wrong permissions when installing pip, check if you are using the correct binary of easy_install. You can select the binary in the virtualenv explicitly by `./venv/bin/easy_install pip`.

Answer (score 50):

It is easier than as it seems:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 yourenv
source yourenv/bin/activate
pip install package-name
```

really works :)

Comment: That should be correct answer

Comment: Yeah ! That was super easy ! Thanks man. @Cem Yildiz

Answer (score 11):

You are doing this far too complicated. If it's included in `python3`, just create it with :

```
python3 -m venv
```

You can even create an alias if you wish to

```
alias virtualenv3='python3 -m venv'
```

Depending on the machine, you might need to specify the interpreter:

```
alias virtualenv3='python3 -m venv -p python3'
```

Comment: The package `python3-venv` is also needed, at least on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: For me (also on 14.04), the package was called `python3.4-venv`.

Comment: on version 18.04, too

Answer (score 2):

The steps that worked for me:
On MAC OSX 10.9.5

1. Download and install [Python-3.4.3 manually](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/).

   ```
   P3PATH=/Users/$USER/Python3
   mkdir -p $P3PATH
   cd $P3PATH
   tar -zxvf Python-3.4.3.tgz
   ./configure --prefix=$P3PATH/Python-3.4.3
   make; make install
   ```
2. Create a virtualenv.

   ```
   $P3PATH/Python-3.4.3/bin/pyvenv py3env
   source py3env/bin/activate
   ```

Note:
 `virtualenv -p <path to python3> py3env` did not work:

```
Error due to zlib
```

Comment: This also works fine on Debian 7 (wheezy). Just another P3PATH

Comment: For the debian based distro in-a-container users, make sure to install `libssl-dev` and `zlib1g-dev` so that python is compiled with _ssl.so zlib.so

Answer (score 1):

```
On Ubuntu 14.04 

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

sudo pip install virtualenv

virtualenv-3.4 --no-site-packages venv
```

Answer (score 0):

just be sure that you installed `pip` and `venv`:

```bsh
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

Then you can use it like this:

```bsh
python3 -m venv ~/env-sample
. ~/env-sample/bin/activate
```